# Why do my ONNXRuntime Inference crash on GPU without any log?

Tags: c#, deep-learning, pytorch, onnxruntime

I am trying to run a ONNX model in C# created with pytorch in Python for image segmentation. Everything works fine when I run it on CPU but when I try to use the GPU my application crash when trying to run the inference.
(Everything works fine when doing the inference in python with GPU)

The only thing I have is an event in the Windows 10 Event Viewer :

> Faulting application name: DeepLearningONNX.exe, version: 1.0.0.0,
> time stamp: 0x6331eb0e Faulting module name: cudnn64_8.dll, version:
> 6.14.11.6050, time stamp: 0x62e9c226 Exception code: 0xc0000409 Fault offset: 0x000000000001420d Faulting process id: 0x2cc0 Faulting
> application start time: 0x01d8f830aac6f0a2 Faulting application path:
> C:\R&D\DeepLearningONNX\DeepLearningONNX\bin\x64\Debug\net6.0-windows\DeepLearningONNX.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
> Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin\cudnn64_8.dll Report Id:
> 40803e1a-e84d-4645-bfb6-4ebbb6ba1b78 Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

**My Hardware :**

NVIDIA Quadro P620 (4GB). Driver 31.0.15.1740

Intel Core i7-10850H

Windows 10 22H2 OS build 19045.2251

**In my Environment system variables :**

CUDA_PATH : *C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6*

CUDA_PATH_V11_6 : *C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6*

PATH : *C:\Program Files\NVIDIA\CUDNN\v8.5*;*C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin*;*C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\libnvvp*

**In my C# (.NET 6) solution. The nuget installed :**

Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Gpu version 1.13.1

**Softwares installed :**

Visual Studio Community 2022 (64bit) version 17.3.6

cuda_11.6.2_511.65_windows.exe

cudnn-windows-x86_64-8.5.0.96_cuda11-archive extracted in *C:\Program Files\NVIDIA\CUDNN\v8.5*

**My code C# :**

```
private void InferenceDebug(string modelPath, bool useGPU)
        {
            InferenceSession session;

            if (useGPU)
            {
                var cudaProviderOptions = new OrtCUDAProviderOptions();
                var providerOptionsDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                providerOptionsDict["device_id"] = "0";
                providerOptionsDict["gpu_mem_limit"] = "2147483648";
                providerOptionsDict["arena_extend_strategy"] = "kSameAsRequested";
                providerOptionsDict["cudnn_conv_algo_search"] = "DEFAULT";
                providerOptionsDict["do_copy_in_default_stream"] = "1";
                providerOptionsDict["cudnn_conv_use_max_workspace"] = "1";
                providerOptionsDict["cudnn_conv1d_pad_to_nc1d"] = "1";

                cudaProviderOptions.UpdateOptions(providerOptionsDict);

                SessionOptions options = SessionOptions.MakeSessionOptionWithCudaProvider(cudaProviderOptions);
                session = new InferenceSession(modelPath, options);
            }
            else
                session = new InferenceSession(modelPath);

            int w = 128;
            int h = 128;
            Tensor<float> input = new DenseTensor<float>(new int[] { 1, 3, h, w });
            Random random = new Random(42);

            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
                {
                    input[0, 0, y, x] = (float)(random.NextDouble() / 255);
                    input[0, 1, y, x] = (float)(random.NextDouble() / 255);
                    input[0, 2, y, x] = (float)(random.NextDouble() / 255);
                }
            }

            var inputs = new List<NamedOnnxValue> { NamedOnnxValue.CreateFromTensor<float>("modelInput", input) };
            using IDisposableReadOnlyCollection<DisposableNamedOnnxValue> results = session.Run(inputs); // The crash is when executing this line
        }
```

**My Code Python (3.10 64bit) :**

```
import torch # version '1.12.1+cu116'
from torch import nn
import segmentation_models_pytorch as smp
from segmentation_models_pytorch.losses import DiceLoss

class SegmentationModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(SegmentationModel, self).__init__()

    self.arc = smp.UnetPlusPlus(encoder_name= 'timm-efficientnet-b0',
                        encoder_weights='imagenet',
                        in_channels= 3,
                        classes = 1,
                        activation=None)
    
  def forward(self,images, masks=None):
    logits = self.arc(images)

    if masks != None :
      loss1 =DiceLoss(mode='binary')(logits, masks)
      loss2 = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()(logits, masks)
      return logits, loss1+loss2
    
    return logits

modelPath = "D:/model.pt"
device = "cuda"#input("Enter device (cpu or cuda) : ")
model = SegmentationModel()
model.to(device);
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(modelPath,map_location=torch.device(device) ))
model.eval()

dummy_input = torch.randn(1,3,128,128,device=device)

torch.onnx.export(model,         # model being run 
        dummy_input,       # model input (or a tuple for multiple inputs) 
        "model.onnx",       # where to save the model  
        export_params=True,  # store the trained parameter weights inside the model file 
        do_constant_folding=True,  # whether to execute constant folding for optimization 
        input_names = ['modelInput'],   # the model's input names 
        output_names = ['modelOutput'], # the model's output names 
        dynamic_axes={'modelInput' : [0,2,3],    # variable length axes 
    

                    'modelOutput' : [0,2,3]})
```

What is the cause of the crash and how can I fix it?

Comment: erratum : Here is the repo containing the ONNX and pt models : https://github.com/leoc70/ONNXRuntime-model-debug

Comment: There is no neeed for erratums, you can always edit your own question to add a link or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I forgot to download the zlib as mentioned here :
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#prerequisites-windows

After adding in my  environment variable PATH the path to the zlibwapi.dll folder everything works.